# Ampère's law of circulation: The direction of current is the technical direction (+ to -) or the direction of flow of the electrons?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Ampère's law of circulation is expressed as
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{B} &= \,\frac{\partial \, \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial \, t}.
\end{align}.

[image]

Is E in the equation the technical direction of the current (from + to -) or the real flow of the electrons (from - to +)?

Are there experiments with a ray of electrons and the measured magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

$\vec E$ is the electrical field which points in the direction of the force on a positive charge and $I$ relates to the rate of flow of positive charges.

When dealing with electrons I find it easier to first treat them as being positively charged and the switch signs as appropriate.

Comment: And, the image shows the flow of electrons, while the equation is related to positive charges?

Comment: What makes you think that the image shows a flow of electrons?

Comment: I do not know of an experiment to directly measure the magnetic field produced by a beam of electrons.

Comment: “… image shows a flow of electrons?”. Because electrons are mobile in a current.

Comment: Background: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4184214/maxwell-s-equations-for-two-waves-shifted-by-a-quarter-of-wavelength

Answer (score 1):

> Is E in the equation the technical direction of the current (from + to -) or the real flow of the electrons (from - to +)?

$\mathbf{E}$ in the equation is the electric field vector.

There are no electrons mentioned in the equation you cited.

An electron in an electric field experiences a force in the direction opposite to the direction of the electric field vector. But that does not necessarily tell you the direction the electron moves. The electron might be fixed in place by some means (being bound to a fixed atomic nucleus, for example), or it might have inertia in some other direction (for example in a CRT where the deflection plates apply a field transverse to the direction of the motion of the electrons).

Finally, the diagram you shared does not apply to the equation. The diagram illustrates the magnetic field generated by a conduction current

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{B} = \mu_0\boldsymbol{J}$$

which was Ampere's original circuital law. The equation you gave gives the contribution to the magnetic field from a *displacement current* which was Maxwell's addition to the circuital law.

The full form for the curl of the magnetic field includes both terms:

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{B} = \mu_0\boldsymbol{J} + \mu_0\varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t} $$

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to make an indirect verification of the signs of the law. A wire under a compass in the direction North-South, with the ends conneted to a battery. If the positive side is South and negative is North, the needle deflects to the East. By convention the Earth B-field is South to North. Using the right hands rule, with the thumb along the wire and pointing to the negative side, the fingers point to the East. As the right hands rule is a translation of the curl, that means that the curl of the magnetic field and the (conventional) current have the same sign.

We then can imagine a capacitor being charged below the compass, instead of a current in the wire. While the (conventional) transient current is flowing, the same magnetic effect happens. And that means an increasing of the electric field in the direction South to North. So the sign is also the same in both sides of the equation.